# Supporting new PayPal certificates on AppHarbor (SHA-256)

Tags: ssl, certificate, sha256, appharbor, verisign

PayPal recently announced that they upgrade the certificate to SHA-256 with VeriSign G5 Root Certificate.

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US

Does AppHarbor have this root certificate installed?

Does it support SHA-256?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes SHA-256 is supported, and root certificates are updated regularly and automatically. I can also confirm that the VeriSign G5 Root Certificate mentioned in the PayPal article is installed and trusted on the platform.